# Get numbers from string python

Tags: python, arrays, string, split, dataset

I am facing the following problem. I am trying to download this dataset:
[Dataset link](http://cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/datasets/s1.txt)

in this way:

```py
data_file_url = 'http://cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/datasets/s1.txt'
D = np.array(pd.read_csv(data_file_url,header=0))
D = D[ np.random.choice(np.arange(D.shape[0]), D.shape[0], replace=False) ,:]
Dx = D[:,0:2]
Dy = D[:,2]
```

but it seems that is comes in a .txt array format. Thats not really the problem, but the string itself is. It comes in this form:

```py
[['    665845    557965']
 ['    597173    575538']
 ['    618600    551446']
 ...
 ['    650661    861267']
 ['    599647    858702']
 ['    684091    842566']]
```

, where all the arrays are a giant wierd string with a lot of blanc spaces and two number which are the coordinates. I am trying to get it in this form `[123124412, 12312442]`

The dataset can be downloaded in .txt or .ts format.

I tried to split, then cast to `int` but I am getting all the number instead of 2, obviously.

Thanks for the help or advice!

Comment: You need to set the separator to tab instead of comma https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Something like `pd.read_csv(url, sep="\r\t")`. I think this might also clean up your whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the optional arguments of pd.read_csv?
Try the following:
`D = np.array(pd.read_csv(data_file_url,header=0,delimiter='    '))`

Comment: That worked! I did not try that because not all number of the white spaces were the same. But It seems that I miss calculated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
splitted = []

for nums in D:
    first, second = nums[0].split()
    first, second = int(first), int(second)
    splitted.append([first, second])

D = np.array(splitted)
```